# Setting focus with primefaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have an application which is used to update a company's stock. I want a page with two inputTexts. The first one where i enter an item's ID and the press . The Focus then goes to the second inputText, the stock amount of the item. That works fine. Then, when i modify the amount and press , the item is saved and the Focus should go back to the first inputText. It does but it then directly jumps to the second inputText again. Any idea?

```
<div id="page-content">
   <h:form id="frmItem" prependId="false">
      <p:focus id="focus" context="frmItem:itemNo" />

      <p:messages id="vmsgs" severity="error,warn" autoUpdate="true" />
      <p:panelGrid id="inventoryHeader" columns="3" columnClasses="form-label,form-input" styleClass="form-grid">

         <p:outputLabel for="itemNo" value="item no." />
         <p:inputText id="itemNo" autocomplete="off" value="#{wmsItemInventoryActionBean.itemNo}"
            onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){onchange();return false;}">
            <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form:focus,@form:stockAmount,@this"
               listener="#{wmsItemInventoryActionBean.itemNo}" oncomplete="stockAmount.select()" />
         </p:inputText>
         <p:message for="itemNo" />

         <p:outputLabel for="stockAmount" value="stock" />
         <p:inputText id="stockAmount" autocomplete="off" value="#{wmsItemInventoryActionBean.stockAmount}" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){onchange();return false;}">
            <p:ajax process="@form" listener="#{wmsItemInventoryActionBean.save()}" oncomplete="itemNo.focus()"/>
         </p:inputText>
         <p:message for="stockAmount" />

      </p:panelGrid> 
   </h:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
update="@form:focus"

<p:inputText id="stockAmount" autocomplete="off" value="#{wmsItemInventoryActionBean.stockAmount}" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){onchange();return false;}">
    <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form:focus" listener="#{wmsItemInventoryActionBean.save()}" oncomplete="itemNo.focus()"/>
</p:inputText>
```